# Jenkins is not loading outside the server using https

Tags: xml, jenkins, https, server, web-hosting

I have a Jenkins Hosted in a Azure windows server. The application is up and running in Server.I need to implement https for jenkins and i implemented it with the help of keysotore. https is working fine in server but unable to access outside the server, but http is accessible outside the server.

Configuration details:

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --httpsPort=8343 --httpsKeyStore="%BASE%\secrets\keystore1" --httpsKeyStorePassword=testing@1 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

Note:

1. Used the port for https 8343
2. while http is accessible outside the server used the port 8080
3. Swiped the port and checked at that time http for port 8343 worked fine.
4. Trying to use the https 8343 port the browser only rotates.
5. Jenkins verson 2.107.3